# C# web browser and access to opened fileopendialog

Tags: c#, browser, filedialog

i develop a program and it has a webbrowser.

i want to set opened filedialog `s defaultPath (InitialDirectory).[How to access a file browser opened by a WebBrowser control]

and how to set file automatic by me ?

Comment: what do you mean by [How to access a file browser opened by a WebBrowser control]?

Comment: i set  opened file browser my Image Path and i want to set default Path ( in C# InitialDirectory ) ! 
expression very clearly. ;)

Comment: Post the code that created the open file dialog. Or is it created by someone else? If so, how did you invoke the file dialog?

Comment: what is you exact question? i'm totally confused

Answer (score 1):

you can Use Windows API (user32.dll) to change Directory dialog.
for example:
to get handler of FileDialog window

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint = "FindWindow", SetLastError = true)]
private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

private const int WM_SETTEXT = 0x000C;

IntPtr FileDialogHandle = FindWindow("#32770", "Choose File To Upload");
```

To get handler Textbox file address of FileDialog window and send path:

```
IntPtr iptrHWndControl = GetDlgItem(FileDialogHandle , 1148);
HandleRef hrefHWndTarget = new HandleRef(null, iptrHWndControl);
SendMessage(hrefHWndTarget, WM_SETTEXT, IntPtr.Zero, "your file path");
```

Comment: Hi and Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read the [How to Answer a Question Guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer). This site is a Q&A site not a forum. Please add an example or further details on how to make use of the user32.dll.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set the default path.

Comment: why not ? its posible in delphi but .NET maybe ? 
Is it possible I wonder where C# . 
and i see program codded with delphi .